How to develop Gitlab Pipeline to integrate with Code Beamer Ticket ID status?
I have the below requirements which couldnot be achieved with ./git/hooks and PUSH rules.
Reason Being is ./git/hooks are local and once if user clones the repo, these changes wont be visible. In PUSH rules condition, the regex for commit message follows only if Branch is Protected.
Requirements:

The commit message shall start with ‘#’, followed by 7 digits, A Space, & 3-400 characters.
eg: #1234567 Implementation
#1234567 is the Ticket ID from Code beamer. git commit operation should be valid, only is this Ticket ID is in OPEN status in code beamer.

